# Using postMessage() between Android and Website

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, joomla

I have a mobile App that navigate to website login page in new window using the following JS onclick:

```
window.open('https://URL', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

The new window opens is as follows:

[image]

I need to populate the username in its field automatically. I found postMessage() method very suitable to do cross-domain communications (e.g., this [example](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/cross-domain-messaging-with-postmessage)) . But I could not find any example of using it between Android and website.

Now I understand that I need to modify on both sides (i.e., source and destination) to use postMessage(). I understand the source side. My question is about the destination as I'm not familiar with Joomla nor I'm familiar with PHP. So the question is, where exactly I need to modify at the destination side, given the page is default Joomla login page. I know where login form in the directory `components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php` ,but I do not know if there where should I update and what exactly should I update there. Should I create iFrame? or I only need to add this method inside login form?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the Android side, if the Android SDK supports some kind of postMessage sending to the window object, then you can use postMessage.

In your case you catch the newly created window in variable:

```
var loginWindow = window.open('https://URL', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Then you can send the postMessage to that window like this:

```
loginWindow.postMessage('Some text here', 'foobar');
```

All you need to do on the login website side is to catch the post event and populate the input field like this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  var message = event.data;
  $('input.login').val(message);
});
```

I am not that familiar with Joomla structure, so I just put some dummy jQuery selector there. If you can not use only JavaScript, then most likely you just need to find a method in Android SDK/Java to create a window element and send a postmessage to that window object. That way you can pass the window object inside Java code.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot see any javascript on the destination side (Joomla). All files are in php. That's why I'm not sure where to write the code. I'm also not familiar with Joomla